# Debug Assertion failed in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, mfc

I'm newbie in C++. I create a small app in MFC C++ in that i used C DLL. Firstly that code running like charm. Now i take licensed visual Studio version 2012. My DLL also upgraded. I using that upgraded DLL in my C++ application and changed code according to newer features. Now my application build successfully. When i run application i got assertion failure error after launched and also i initiate DLL process on launch time. I did not getting why assertion come. Assertion come from the DLL response so i can't6 able to trace code from DLL. I attached its screenshot below,

[image]

Comment and suggestion welcome.

Comment: Please comment before negative vote

Comment: Close before "too board question should write up", my program crash at launch time and error come through 3rd party DLL so i unable to post code.

Comment: It looks like the assert comes from MFC, not from the mysterious DLL.

Comment: Open the debugger, look at the call stack. Which is the last function of your code that is calling something that is not yours? You are probably passing wrong data down. Use the debugger to examine variables. Do they look OK?

Comment: @molbdnilo you are absolutely right. I interested what is meaning of this error and why it asking mfc110ud.dll file what exact matter it came. @ n.m i just write 1 line of code DLLInit(callback, NULL, "MYCODE", DLL_MODE_DEFAULT, stderr);  and in callback thrown above error.

Comment: Looks like this is your lucky day. The error is in the only line of code you added. Remove it and you'll be alright.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for suggestion keep it remember i'm sure one day  your suggestion will helpful to you :) :)

Comment: Look at wincore.cpp line 1091 to understand what it is complaining about. Between that and studying the call stack you should be able to understand or better describe the problem.